# Backwards-compatible XML Deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am deserializing an XML configuration file by performing the following:

```
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyType));
using (TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(fn))
{
    return (MyType)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
}
```

Then I have a simple method to check if the XML configuration file matches the values in the current UI.

```
if ((config.Description == null || config.Description != this.Description.Text)
   || (config.Location == null || config.Location != this.Location.Text)
   || (config.Provider == null || config.Provider != this.Provider.Text))
```

So if I have an older configuration file containing just `config.Description`, then `config.Location` and `config.Provider` will be null when the XML file is deserialized. How can I just simplify this so that `config.Location` is set to the default value for the typed property instead (in this case the strings would be set to zero-length strings), allowing me to drop all the null checks? For example:

```
if (config.Description != this.Description.Text
   || config.Location != this.Location.Text
   || config.Provider != this.Provider.Text)
```

I know one option is to create an instance besides the deserialized instance and loop through all properties using Reflection (or some other similar approach) but I was hoping there was a built-in way to assign default values to properties that weren't deserialized. I'm mostly wondering if this is the correct approach, as I'm trying to reduce unnecessary bloat when dealing with a larger amount of settings.

I've searched for duplicates of this problem, but most people are trying to deserialize an instance into itself and using the serialization event to control that behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `XmlSerializer` requires a parameterless constructor. However you can use any of the initialization techniques as shown below:

```
public class MyType
{
    private string _description = default(string); // Note the default is NULL, not "" for a string

    // However, why not determine the default yourself?
    private string _location = "";
    private string _provider;

    public MyType()
    {
        // Or use the constructor to set the defaults
        _provider = string.Empty;
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return _description; }
        set { _description = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. I've been working with VBA types too much lately. I expected "" from `public string Description{ get; set; }`... I forgot to check the constructor, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"..I was hoping there was a built-in way to assign default values to properties that weren't deserialized.."
You can set default values in the class constructor.